# Splitting of string for `whitespace` & `and`

Tags: java, string, split

```
String filter = phoneNumber eq '763436' and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith '256'
```

the split should give me the following:

> String 1 = phoneNumber eq 763436
>
> String 2 = carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility'
>
> String 3 = site startswith 256

Further more String 1 2 and 3 should split into

> String operator = phoneNumer String operator = eq String operand =763436
>
> String operator = carrier String operator = eq String operand =AT and T Mobility
>
> String operator = site String operator = startswith String operand =256

I can use string.split("and") and split(" ") for outer and inner respectively, but my string too contains whitespace and and also (example AT and T Mobility). One help is that extra and and white space will be present in operator only within quotes.

Any Help how to split in java?

Comment: Sorry my filter string is like below: String filter ="phoneNumber eq 763436 and carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith 256"  only 'AT and T Mobility' will be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want those string as key,operand,value you can try this

```
    String regex="(?<key>\\S+)\\s+(?<operator>\\S+)\\s+(?<value>'[^']*'|\\S+)";
    for(String s:filter.split("\\s*and\\s*(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)"))
    {
        Matcher m=Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Key:"+m.group("key"));
            System.out.println("operator:"+m.group("operator"));
            System.out.println("Value:"+m.group("value"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ur ones help but i need the following way first split should give me to split based on and and like String 1 = phoneNumber eq '763436' String 2 = carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' String 3 = site startswith 256 and then next split should split individual string as operator operand and value. Basically i am looking for split method twice.

Comment: I'd suggest surrounding `and` with `\\s*` so that you don't unnecessarily split on redundant spaces, like so: `split("(\\s*and\\s*|\\s+)(?=([^']*'[^']*')*$)")`.

Comment: Guys I hope u r getting my concerns I dont need all split in one go. I need split method twice one to split at and level and another split to split the result string based on white space. Look at my example.

Comment: @RohanK once you split into individual tokens like above you can keep on taking three elements at a time from array as key,operand,value

Comment: @Anirudh Thanks Bro .... I agree but i need to pass that Level 1 string to a service than the service will split it again to three different strings..  wat u mentioned is correct but service expects only one single string form my side. Any help?

Comment: @RohanK edit would also handle cases where values are not within `'`

Comment: @RohanK yeah sure :-)...you can accept the ans if that helped

Comment: Hey @Anirudha ... If operator contains hypen .. like phone-Number contains 9 so if i use ur suggested way, its only taking operator as -Number not phone-Number. Please help here..

Answer (score 2):

Since `split` is regex-based, and if I'm reading the question correctly, you can just split for either one:

```
String[] split = yourString.split("(and)|\s+");
```

**Edit**:

Rather than splitting through regex for this, I would honestly recommend parsing the string yourself for something this specific:

```
public String[] parseRawString(String raw) {
    List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //whether or not to split on spaces
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    for (char c : raw.toCharArray()) {
        //if a quote is found
        if (c == '\'') {
            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        //if a space is found outside quotes
        } else if (char == ' ' && !inQuotes) {
            args.add(sb.toString());
            sb.clear();
        //if a normal character is found or we're inside a quote
        } else if (char != ' ' || inQuotes) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    //add any last remnants that weren't added before the end
    if (!sb.isEmpty()) {
        args.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return args.toArray(new String[args.size()]);
}
```

This allows for some easier parsing:

```
String[] one = parseRawString("phoneNumber eq 763436");
/*
    one[0] = phoneNumber
    one[1] = eq
    one[2] = 763436
*/
String[] two = parseRawString("carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility'");
/*
    two[0] = carrier
    two[1] = eq
    two[2] = AT and T Mobility
*/
//etc...
```

That seems a bit closer to what you want, I believe.

Comment: The answer just needs the following change: Remove the ampersand `&` and place `and` instead of it, so it will look something like so: `(and)|\s+`.

Comment: Updating in accordance, thanks for that catch @npinti

Comment: npinti still not helping see 1st split should give me string 1 2 and 3 than further split of each string should give operand operator and value. Apologies if my question framing was nt up to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out This Answer.
It's working

**PROGRAM:**

```
    String filter = "phoneNumber eq 763436 and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith 256";
    String[] split = filter.split("\\s*and\\s*(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
    for (String s : split) {
       String[] split1 = s.trim().split(" ",3);
       for (String s1 : split1) {
            System.out.println(""+s1.replaceAll("'", ""));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    phoneNumber
    eq
    763436
    carrier
    eq
    AT and T Mobility
    site
    startswith
    256
```

**Check out the updated program as that one works for all types of input strings like below,**

**1.String filter = "'phone Number' eq '763436' and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site 'startswith' '256'";**

**2.String filter = "'phone Number' eq '763436' and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site 'starts with' '256'";**

**3.String filter = "'phone and Number' eq '763436' and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site 'starts with' '256'";**

**4.String filter = "phoneNumber eq '763436' and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith '256'";**

**5.String filter = "phoneNumber eq 763436 and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith 256";**

**even more you can as many strings like above with as single quotes.it's working for all of them..**

**UPDATED PROGRAM**

```
    String filter = "'phone Number' eq 763436 and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site 'startswith' '256'";
    String[] split = filter.split("\\s*and\\s*(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
    for (String s : split) {
        String[] split1 = s.trim().split("\\s* \\s*(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
        for (String s1 : split1) {
            System.out.println("" + s1.replaceAll("'", ""));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    phone Number
    eq
    763436
    carrier
    eq
    AT and T Mobility
    site
    startswith
    256
```

Check the updated code and update the status

Comment: Prakash what if the filter is phoneNumber eq 763436 and  carrier eq 'AT and T Mobility' and site startswith 256   I removed single quotes from numbers

Comment: @RohanK Check out the updated answer.it's working perfectly for many string values as mentioned in my answer.check it and update

Comment: thank you. I checked it worked. But I like the Matcher and Regex way of Anirudhh. But really thanks for the effort.