# how to split a string by "|"

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to use regular expression to split this string:

```
String filter = "(go|add)addition|(sub)subtraction|(mul|into)multiplication|adding(add|go)values|(add|go)(go)(into)multiplication|";
```

I want to split it by `|` except when the pipe appears within brackets in which case they should be ignored, i.e. I am excepting an output like this:

```
(go|add)addition
(sub)subtraction
(mul|into)multiplication
adding(add|go)values
(add|go)(go)(into)multiplication
```

**Updated**

And then i want to move the words within the brackets at the start to the end.

Something like this..

```
addition(go|add)
subtraction(sub)
multiplication(mul|into)
adding(add|go)values
multiplication(add|go)(go)(into)
```

I have tried this regular expression: [Splitting of string for `whitespace` & `and`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678833/splitting-of-string-for-whitespace-and) but they have used quotes and I have not been able to make it work for brackets.

Comment: If you want to use a single regex for this operation, then you'll need to get *very* familiar with the lookahead and lookbehind syntax `(?...)`

Comment: @DerGolem check out the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678833/splitting-of-string-for-whitespace-and) i have posted..they have used ' and i want to use ()..

Comment: @DerGolem that isn't true.  It is possible with lookahead/lookbehind

Comment: Are the parenthesis always at the beginning? Are they always there?

Comment: I'd better use a **unique separator char**, as in `"(go|add)addition;(sub)subtraction;(mul|into)multiplication"` (note that the last separator is useless). Here the separator is **;**

Comment: @Robin not always in between also it's there..

Comment: check out the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678833/splitting-of-string-for-whitespace-and)

Comment: That algorithm doesn't seem much performing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *don't* have nested parenthesis (so *not* `(mul(iple|y)|foo)`) you can use:

```
((?:\([^)]*\))*)([^()|]+(?:\([^)]*\)[^()|]*)*)

(                          #start first capturing group
    (?:                    # non capturing group
         \([^)]*\)         # opening bracket, then anything except closing bracket, closing bracket
    )*                     # possibly multiple bracket groups at the beginning
)
(                          # start second capturing group
    [^()|]+                # go to the next bracket group, or the closing |
    (?:
        \([^)]*\)[^()|]*   # bracket group, then go to the next bracket group/closing |
     )*                    # possibly multiple brackets groups
)                          # close second capturing group
```

and replace with

```
\2\1
```

**Explanation**

- `((?:\([^)]*\))*)` matches and captures all the parenthesis groups at the beginning
- `[^()|]*` anything except `(`, `)`, or `|`. If there isn't any parenthesis, this will match everything.
- `(?:\([^)]*\)[^()|]*)`: `(?:...)` is a non capturing group, `\([^)]*\)` matches everything inside parenthesis, `[^()|]*` gets us up to the next parenthesis group or the `|` that ends the match.

---

**Code sample:**

```
String testString = "(go|add)addition|(sub)subtraction|(mul|into)multiplication|adding(add|go)values|(add|go)(go)(into)multiplication|";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:\\([^)]*\\))*)([^()|]+(?:\\([^)]*\\)[^()|]*)*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2)+m.group(1));
}
```

**Outputs** ([demo](http://ideone.com/2cHaQV)):

```
addition(go|add)
subtraction(sub)
multiplication(mul|into)
adding(add|go)values
multiplication(add|go)(go)(into)
```

Comment: no the paramets were optional and they can be at any places like this String filter = "(go|add)addition|(sub)subtraction|(mul|into)multiplication|multiplication|multipl(mul|into)ication|";

Comment: yah i got it can you do me one more favour by adding the brackets to the end of the string like addition(go|add) pls...

Comment: @Prakash: **1**. I saw in another comment that you can have `(foo|bar(foobar))`? These are nested constructs, much harder to do. My current answer won't catch them. **2**. You want all parenthesis to the end? What happens to `multiplication(foo)bar(foobar)`?

Comment: @Prakash The key to a good question on SO is to give ***all*** the relevant information in your question. None of the answers you have received so far solve your problem because you did not give enough details (in particular the fact that the `(..|..)` could be anywhere, not just at the beginning and that there could be nested brackets).

Comment: @Prakash: please edit your question to add *all* your requirements.

Comment: @Robin it's ok i can manage with (foo|bar(foobar)) kind of strings as i don't have many of them as i checked...i want the words within the brackets at the start to be moved to the end with brackets.... check out my updated question...

Comment: @Robin moving the words can be done separately after spliting..if you can do while spliting also no problem...

Comment: @Robin can you explain the regex that moves the word within brackets to the end seperately a bit more briefly pls.....

Comment: @Robin can you put the regex that moves the word within brackets to the end seperately pls.....

Comment: @Robin thanks i have added another question regarding this...almost the same before seeing your answer..can you help me on that one as well....plssssss

Comment: @Robin see this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623651/how-to-move-the-the-words-within-the-brackets-to-the-end-of-the-string)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52567/discussion-between-prakash-and-robin)

Comment: @Robin what i had to do if instead of () i want to use [] ..can you put the regex in comment pls....

Comment: @Robin what i had to do if instead of () i want to use [] or both..can you put the regex in comment pls.... –

Comment: @Prakash: No time for chat right now, sorry. I gave a quick answer to your other question, and the stackoverflow community should also kick in.

Answer (score 3):

Already seen this question 15 min ago. Now that it is asked correctly, here is my proposition of answer :

Trying with a regex is complex because you need to count parenthesis. I advice you to manually parse the string like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String filter = "(go|add)addition|(sub)subtraction|(mul|into)multiplication|";

  List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
  int countParenthesis = 0;
  StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();

  for(char c : filter.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == '(') {countParenthesis ++;}
    if(c == ')') {countParenthesis --;}
    if(c == '|' && countParenthesis == 0) {
      strings.add(current.toString());
      current = new StringBuilder();
    } else {
      current.append(c);
    }
  }
  strings.add(current.toString());

  for (String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(string+" ");
  }

}
```

Output :

```
(go|add)addition 
(sub)subtraction 
(mul|into)multiplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String

"(go|add)addition|(sub)subtraction|(mul|into)multiplication|"

have a pattern |( from where you can split for this particular String pattern. But this wont give expected result if your sub string contains paranthesis( "(" ) in between ex:

(go|(add))addition.... continue

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Set up bool to keep track if you are inside a parenthesis or not.

Bool isInside = True;

```
loop through string
if char at i = ")" isInside = False
if isInside = false
code for skipping |
else
code for leaving | here
```

something like this should work i think.