# How to move the the words within the brackets to the end of the string

Tags: java, regex

I am in need of a regex to do this, to move words with bracket from the start to the end of a string.

This is my string array...

```
"{"[foo](foo)(foo)bar","bar","(foo)[foo]bar","[foo]bar(foo)bar"}"
```

and I want to move the words within the brackets and the square brackets in the start, to the end of the string. Something like this...

```
bar[foo](foo)(foo)
bar
bar(foo)[foo]
bar(foo)bar[foo]
```

the order is not necessary, but I only want to move the words within the brackets at the start, as previously stated. The words within the middle brackets can stay in the same location.

Can someone please help to do this? Notify me if there are any errors or uncertainty in my question.

Comment: Have you tried writing any regex that would do what you would like it to do?

Comment: Take a look at the `string#substring()` method that method will find strings based on position.

Comment: replace(), split(), subString() (in this order) will help you. regex alone will not help

Comment: Does the end of your strings always end in a word?

Comment: not always sometimes it will be like bar(foo) also in this case nothing has to be done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each string you can replace

```
((?:\[[^\]]*\]|\([^)]*\))*)(.+)

(                     # first capturing group
    (?:               # non capturing group
        \[ [^\]]* \]  # [, anything but a ], ] 
    |                 # OR
        \( [^)]* \)   # (, anything but a ), )
    )*                # any number of (square) bracket groups
)                     # close first capturing group
(.+)                  # capture the rest of the string
```

with

```
\2\1
```

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/fH0nR0).

Don't forget that in Java special characters must be escaped twice, so the regex will become `((?:\\[[^\\]]*\\]|\\([^)]*\\))*)(.+)`.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps :

```
String[] lList = {"[foo](foo)(foo)bar","bar","(foo)[foo]bar","[foo]bar(foo)bar"};
    for(int i=0; i<lList.length; i++) {
        String lString = lList[i].trim();
        System.out.println("Before : " + lString);
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done) {
            if(lString.startsWith("[")) {
                lString = lString.replaceAll("(\\[[^\\]]+\\])(.*)", "$2" + "$1");
            }
            else if(lString.startsWith("(")) {
                lString = lString.replaceAll("(\\([^\\)]+\\))(.*)", "$2" + "$1");
            }
            else {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After : " + lString);
    }
```

The Output is :

```
Before : [foo](foo)(foo)bar
After : bar[foo](foo)(foo)
Before : bar
After : bar
Before : (foo)[foo]bar
After : bar(foo)[foo]
Before : [foo]bar(foo)bar
After : bar(foo)bar[foo]
```